# How to fix Beveled intersections/corners/inner edges?

Tags: edges, bevel

I'm pretty new to Blender and am trying to create a 3D type logo. It's almost done, but I can't figure out how to fix these inner corners circled in red (see images below).

[image]

[image]

To create the rounded edges I am using the Bevel Modifier that references the model's edge data (I gave all the sharp edges a Bevel Weight of 1). It's then followed up by a Subdivision Surface modifier to smooth things out.

Any help would be much appreciated (I'm not even sure if I modeled this thing correctly so I attached the Blend file). Thanks!

[JT Logo White.blend](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11CC0ObJKEtsHdvr6KKxOEIyaxHKy101N)

Comment: Your mesh has poor topology, strive for a quad dominant topology. Also not sure why you are using a subsurf modifier on top of a bevel, for what basically seems to be a hard surface model

Comment: Hi @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, Thanks for the response. I'm pretty new to all this and I'm just now learning what a hard surface model is, and yeah this is probably a hard surface model haha. How would you go about modeling this correctly? And how would you fix the topology? The way I made this was starting with an SVG of the J and extruding the curves, then filling in the blank faces with F which gave me a bunch of ngons which I converted to tris and then to quads (but it obviously didn't get rid of all the tris). I know this is probably all wrong btw, but it's my first stab at it ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: *Subsurf* here seems unnecessary. Cleaning up your topology should solve most issues. This may help https://topologyguides.com

Comment: Thanks @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I'll have a look

Answer (score 1):

As Duarte said, the Subsurf is not necessary and you need to clean your topology, the following method gives a good result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response @moonboots. I followed what you said and it definitely helped clean up the topology, but now I'm getting weird shading and faceting

Comment: please share your new version