# How to fix ugly bevel in inner corner?

Tags: modifiers, edges, bevel

so I feel a bit sorry about asking the probably 1000th question about the bevel modifier. Long story short, I'm having some issues with an ugly bevel in my model and I don't quite understand what's causing it:

[image: bad bevel]

Now, it seems to me that there might be a relation to that additional edge that I have in the green box and which I don't have in the red box. However, when manually inserting an edge on the left side like I have on the right side, it doesn't change anything (selecting both vertices, then 'F').
Also, from what I know there are no inner faces in my model.

I've checked through other bevel related questions. The closest one I could find was this one:
[How to fix Beveled intersections/corners/inner edges?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120141/how-to-fix-beveled-intersections-corners-inner-edges)

Still, is there any difference for me using the bevel modifier instead of the one that works on the mesh directly? Also, I'm not quite sure what a good topology is supposed to look like.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your edge theory is right. The face the corner is in is something called an N-gon. It is usually discouraged due to several problems with its internal handling.

When you create that edge using <kbd>F</kbd>, the created edge does not separate the face, so the N-gon stays. In order to actually cut the face, use the Knife Tool <kbd>K</kbd> in Edit Mode. Select one of the vertices. You will see there is now a square and a purple line. Now click on the other vertex and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Now, the N-gon is separated.

The N-gon gets split into more N-gons, so you might want to use the Knife Tool more to separate it into quads and triangles (which is good topology).

Your corner is now fixed.

Documentation on Knife Tool: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/knife.html

Comment: Thank you very much. This did indeed fix it. However, you mentioned using N-gon is discouraged. Does this basically mean that I should only use quads and triangles to avoid that kind of thing?

Comment: @thelpatix Yes, you should. In fact, try to use quads as much as possible over the other two, because it results in cleaner topology, and all Blender operations just handle quads better than the other two.

Comment: While `F` creates an edge over the top of an existing face, `J` will cut the underlying face and can be easier than the knife.